# Unable to open AVD Manager and layout files

Tags: java, android, eclipse-plugin

I have updated my Android SDK Tools to latest version(24.0.1). But it shows the following error dialog while  I am trying to open my layout files by double clicking it (Open With Android Common XML Editor)

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.getDevices(Ljava/util/EnumSet;)Ljava/util/Collection;
```

Also, I am unable to open AVD Manager by clicking its icon.But while running my application, shows list of emulators and able to launch the emulator. Why does this happens?

Comment: well updating ADT in eclipse in broken. You need to download updated package from android website

Comment: When I am trying to update adt from Eclipse(Help->Install New Software) shows error 'Unable to complete the install because of a conflicting dependency'.

Comment: that's why I have its broken. You need to download the new package from android website.